# Как создать вертикальную полосу загрузки с использованием :hover?

Tags: html, css, css3

В общем нужно создать что-то вроде этого:
https://antontretyak.github.io/Progress , но разместить блок нужно вертикально.

Comment: Какие затруднения у вас возникли при попытке сделать по аналогии с данным вами примером?

Comment: Это всё легчайше тырится из отладчика на той странице, а потом поворачивается одной дополнительной строкой в стилях. Отладчик - бох!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так, просто сделайте `transform rotate`. Поверните `div` на 90 градусов.

```css
.progress {
    width: 400px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #000;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
.progress::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background-color: darkorange;
    -webkit-transition: linear 5s;
    -o-transition: linear 5s;
    transition: all linear 5s;
    height: inherit;
    width: 0;
}
.progress:hover::before {
    width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress"></div>
```

Вариант второй сделайте анимацию не `width` а `height`.

```css
.progress {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 30px;
  background-color: #000;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.progress::before {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: darkorange;
  -webkit-transition: linear 5s;
  -o-transition: linear 5s;
  transition: all linear 5s;
  height: inherit;
  width: 30px;
  height: 0;
}
.progress:hover::before {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress"></div>
```

Если хотите с псевдоэлементом `before` то так. но без `js` идеально не будет.

```css
.progress {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  height: 300px;
  width: 30px;
  background-color: #000;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.progress::before {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: darkorange;
  -webkit-transition: linear 5s;
  -o-transition: linear 5s;
  transition: all linear 5s;
  height: inherit;
  width: 30px;
  height: 0;
}
.progress:nth-child(2)::before{
  background-color: #456123;
}
.progress:nth-child(3)::before{
  background-color: #123789;
}
.progress:nth-child(4)::before{
  background-color: #147255;
}

.progress:hover::before,
.progress:hover ~ .progress::before{
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress"></div>
<div class="progress"></div>
<div class="progress"></div>
<div class="progress"></div>
```

Или так если взять все в контейнер. И сделать `hover` для контейнера.

```css
.cont{
  display: inline-block;
}

.progress {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  height: 300px;
  width: 30px;
  background-color: #000;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.progress::before {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: darkorange;
  -webkit-transition: linear 5s;
  -o-transition: linear 5s;
  transition: all linear 5s;
  height: inherit;
  width: 30px;
  height: 0;
}
.progress:nth-child(2)::before{
  background-color: #456123;
}
.progress:nth-child(3)::before{
  background-color: #123789;
}
.progress:nth-child(4)::before{
  background-color: #147255;
}

.cont:hover .progress::before{
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="progress"></div>
  <div class="progress"></div>
  <div class="progress"></div>
  <div class="progress"></div>
</div>
```

Здесь срабатывает когда наводим на контейнер а не отдельный элемент `.progress`.

Comment: Ага, я тоже использовал Transform, но я поворачивал на 90 градусов, а не на -90 и в итоге не работало.

Comment: @Anton_tr010 Ну ад, и еще второй вариант я дал

Comment: Я вроде сам разобрался, но уже голова кипит, сегодня начал изучать анимации, трансформации. Спасибо за ответ

Comment: А не подскажите, возможно ли сделать так, чтобы при наведении мыши на одну полосу(их будет 4) анимация начиналась для всех?

Comment: если навести на одну то так : https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/EoRwKP

Comment: @Anton_tr010 все возможно, вы определитель с вопросам.

Comment: @МаксимЛенский Зачем в ответе не напишете?